# chart.js plugin for making waterfall charts

Tags: charts, chart.js2

I want to create a chart.js plugin to create waterfall charts.

I am new to working with chart.js. I was thinking to extend the bar-chart to create a waterfall chart.

The draw function in the bar chart controller is as follows:

```
draw: function(ease) {
            var me = this;
            var easingDecimal = ease || 1;
            helpers.each(me.getMeta().data, function(rectangle, index) {
                var d = me.getDataset().data[index];
                if (d !== null && d !== undefined && !isNaN(d)) {
                    rectangle.transition(easingDecimal).draw();
                }
            }, me);
        },
```

THe full bar chart controller js file can be found here: 
https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/tree/master/src/controllers

Comment: Please post your code you have tried so far. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I havent yet started creating the plugin. But I think if we could extend the Bar Chart and convert it into the waterfall chart, it would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since [Chart.js v2.9.0.](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v2.9.0), we can use [floating bars](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/6056) to easily create waterfall charts. Individual bars may since be specified with the syntax `[min, max]`.

Given an array of values `[3, 5, 4, 2, 6]`, we need to produce the following data (last entry being the computed value for the 'Total' bar):

```
[[0, 3], [3, 8], [8, 12], [12, 14], [14, 20], 20]
```

The only additional thing left to do is defining a `tooltips.callback` function that computes the correct value to be shown in the tooltips.

```
tooltips: {
  callbacks: {
    label: (tooltipItem, data) => {
      const v = data.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.index];
      return Array.isArray(v) ? v[1] - v[0] : v;
    }
  }
},
```

Please have a look at the following code sample that produces a waterfall chart out of the `baseData` array.

```js
let baseData = [
 { label: 'A', value: 3 }, 
 { label: 'B', value: 5 }, 
 { label: 'C', value: 4 },
 { label: 'D', value: 2 }, 
 { label: 'E', value: 6 }
];

const labels = baseData.map(o => o.label).concat('Total');
const data = [];
let total = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < baseData.length; i++) {
  const vStart = total;
  total += baseData[i].value;
  data.push([vStart, total]);  
}
data.push(total);
const backgroundColors = data.map((o, i) => 'rgba(255, 99, 132, ' + (i + (11 - data.length)) * 0.1 + ')');

new Chart('waterfall', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      data: data,
      backgroundColor: backgroundColors,
      barPercentage: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: (tooltipItem, data) => {
          const v = data.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.index];
          return Array.isArray(v) ? v[1] - v[0] : v;
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="waterfall" height="200"></canvas>
```

> If the chart should start with the 'Total' bar, simply [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) `labels`, `data` and `backgroundColors` arrays as follows.

```
data: {
  labels: labels.reverse(),
  datasets: [{
    data: data.reverse(),
    backgroundColor: backgroundColors.reverse(),
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

I created a chartjs plugin for waterfall charts.

See https://github.com/MartinDawson/chartjs-plugin-waterfall

> This plugin works by checking if any of your datasets contain a property called dummyStack that is set to true. The stack property must be used in conjunction with dummyStack for this plugin to work properly. If dummyStack is true then it hides the label, tooltip and sets the color invisible. When you use stacking with this it creates the affect of a floating bar as shown in the image above that we can use for waterfall charts as chartjs-2 doesn't support waterfall charts by default.

```
import waterFallPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-waterfall';

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    plugins: [waterFallPlugin]
});

const data = {
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Closing Costs',
      data: [50],
      backgroundColor: '#e8cdd7',
      stack: 'stack 1',
    },
    {
      label: 'Purchase Price',
      data: [700],
      backgroundColor: '#d29baf',
      stack: 'stack 1',
    },
    {
      data: [200],
      dummyStack: true,
      stack: 'stack 2',
    },
    {
      label: 'Opening Loan Balance',
      data: [550],
      backgroundColor: '#bb6987',
      stack: 'stack 2',
    },
    {
      label: 'Initial Cash Investment',
      data: [200],
      backgroundColor: '#a53860',
      stack: 'stack 3',
    },
  ],
};
```

It also has line steps from bar to bar.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to show tciks on x axis using this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin recommented by Chart.JS https://github.com/everestate/chartjs-plugin-waterfall (Ref: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.7.2/notes/extensions.html)

Installation

```
npm install --save chartjs-plugin-waterfall
```

Usage

```
import waterFallPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-waterfall';

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    plugins: [waterFallPlugin]
});
```