# Chart.js how can we have a column not start at 0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, chart.js

I'm trying to make a chart where a couple of the columns need to be floating. How can this be achieved?

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/61708696/2358409 for a solution that works sinceChart.js 2.9.0.

Answer (score 0):

This is a waterfall chart, which is not available in Chart.js. See the issue [on Github](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3077).

However, someone has made such a plugin for Chart.js, [available here](https://github.com/everestate/chartjs-plugin-waterfall).

Usage of this plugin is simple, like so:

```
import waterFallPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-waterfall';

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    plugins: [waterFallPlugin]
});
```