# How to create Waterfall model chart using QuickChart?

Tags: highcharts, chart.js

I am trying to create a waterfall chart using QuickChart. It looks there is no direct way to do such a thing in QuickChart. But, I'm looking if there is any workaround to accomplish this in QuickChart.
Are there any possibilities to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No if quickchart does not support the custom chart type you need you cant use it with quickchart.

You will either need to implement chart.js yourself or look at the source code of quickchart, edit it so it does support the chart type you want to use and host it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It is easily doable with floating bars.

Paste the following chart configuration into https://quickchart.io/sandbox and click on the [Chart URL](https://quickchart.io/sandbox/#%7B%22chart%22%3A%22%7B%5Cr%5Cn%20%20type%3A%20%27bar%27%2C%5Cr%5Cn%20%20data%3A%20%7B%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20labels%3A%20%5B%27Project%20Budget%27%2C%20%27Iteration%201%27%2C%20%27Iteration%202%27%2C%20%27Iteration%203%27%2C%20%27Iteration%204%27%5D%2C%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20datasets%3A%20%5B%7B%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%5B750%2C%20%5B500%2C%20750%5D%2C%20%5B360%2C%20500%5D%2C%20%5B200%2C%20360%5D%2C%20200%5D%2C%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20backgroundColor%3A%20%5B%27rgb(255%2C%200%2C%200)%27%2C%20%27rgba(255%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200.8)%27%2C%20%27rgba(255%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200.6)%27%2C%20%27rgba(255%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200.4)%27%2C%20%27rgba(255%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200.2)%27%5D%2C%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20categoryPercentage%3A%201%2C%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20barPercentage%3A%200.98%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%7D%2C%5Cr%5Cn%20%20options%3A%20%7B%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20responsive%3A%20true%2C%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20maintainAspectRatio%3A%20false%2C%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20legend%3A%20%7B%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20display%3A%20false%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20scales%3A%20%7B%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20yAxes%3A%20%5B%7B%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ticks%3A%20%7B%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20beginAtZero%3A%20true%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cr%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cr%5Cn%7D%22%2C%22width%22%3A500%2C%22height%22%3A300%2C%22version%22%3A%222%22%2C%22backgroundColor%22%3A%22%23fff%22%7D) in the right section of the window.

```
{
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Project Budget', 'Iteration 1', 'Iteration 2', 'Iteration 3', 'Iteration 4'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [750, [500, 750], [360, 500], [200, 360], 200],
      backgroundColor: ['rgb(255, 0, 0)', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8)', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4)', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)'],
      categoryPercentage: 1,
      barPercentage: 0.98
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

> Further information about how it works, is available in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61707906/2358409)

Comment: I did think of this solution but didn't try this because the data is loaded dynamically to the chart. Let me try if I can do something with it.